# Server sent events with Flask and Tornado

Tags: python, flask, tornado, server-sent-events

I have been playing around with sending server sent events with Flask and Tornado.  I took a look at this blog article:

https://s-n.me/blog/2012/10/16/realtime-websites-with-flask/

I decided to try writing my own Flask app to send server sent events as an exercise.  Here is the code for my Flask app called sse_server.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask, request, Response, render_template

from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

app = Flask(__name__)

def event_stream():
  count = 0
  while True:
    print 'data: {0}\n\n'.format(count)
    yield 'data: {0}\n\n'.format(count)
    count += 1

@app.route('/my_event_source')
def sse_request():
  return Response(
          event_stream(),
          mimetype='text/event-stream')

@app.route('/')
def page():
  return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':

  print "Please open a web browser to http://127.0.0.1:5000."

  # Spin up the app
  http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
  http_server.listen(5000)
  IOLoop.instance().start()
```

In my templates folder, I have a simple index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/sse_client.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h3>Test</h3>

  <ul id="output">
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

In my static folder, I have a file called sse_client.js:

```
var queue = [];
var interval = setInterval(function(){addItem()}, 1000);

function addItem(){
  if(queue.length > 0){
    var item = queue[0];
    queue.shift();
    $('#output').append(item);
  }
}

$(document).ready(

  function() {

    var sse = new EventSource('/my_event_source');
    console.log('blah');

    sse.onmessage = function(event) {

      console.log('A message has arrived!');
      var list_item = '<li>' + event.data + '</li>';
      console.log(list_item);
      queue.push(list_item);
    };
})
```

Basically, my app's structure is

```
sse/
  sse_server.py
  static/
    sse_client.js
  templates/
    index.html
```

The app displays the index page, but the data is not getting streamed to it.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  I think I need another set of eyes on this.  I'm sure it's something really minor and stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tornado's WSGIContainer does not support streaming responses from wsgi apps.  You can either use Flask with a multi-threaded or greenlet-based wsgi server, or use Tornado's native RequestHandler interface, but not when you're combining Flask and Tornado with WSGIContainer.

Combining Flask and Tornado is usually not a good idea; see https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/986

Answer (score 0):

To use the url `"../static/sse_client.js"` you need your webserver or your Flask app to serve the static JavaScript file. From the Flask docs:

> To generate URLs for static files, use the special 'static' endpoint
>   name:
>
> `url_for('static', filename='style.css')`
>
> The file has to be stored on the filesystem as static/style.css.

[Read more](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files)

Comment: This is not the problem here, I suppose.